# Why is $2-\sqrt{4-x}$ equal to $\frac{x}{2+\sqrt{4-x}}$?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

As I'm reading a paper, I saw these two formulas equal to each other

$$2-\sqrt{4-x}=\frac{x}{2+\sqrt{4-x}}$$

I'm so confused here, what's the missing step I need to know?

Answer (score 3):

Because $$2-\sqrt{4-x}=\frac{(2-\sqrt{4-x})(2+\sqrt{4-x})}{(2+\sqrt{4-x})}=\frac{4-(4-x)}{2+\sqrt{4-x}}=\frac{x}{2+\sqrt{4-x}}$$

Comment: hmm thank you. I dont know why the author made it to look in rational form but okay. thank you for the help again!

Comment: @clark emily  You are welcome!

Comment: Hello I have a following question, is it okay to ask?

Comment: @clark emily  Yes, of course. Do it.

Answer (score 0):

Without guess the rationalization by direct check using that

$$(A-B)(A+B)=A^2-B^2$$

we obtain

$$2-\sqrt{4-x}=\frac{x}{2+\sqrt{4-x}} \iff \left(2-\sqrt{4-x}\right)(2+\sqrt{4-x})=x$$

which is true.

Comment: Hello I have a following question, is it okay to ask

Comment: @clarkemily Yes of course if it is related to that one. Otherwise you could raise a new question.

Comment: thank you I didn't mean to offend anyone but I got downvoted hard. this question is from the same paper I'm reading:: ----> https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3846692/recursive-formula-generalizaing-next-value

Comment: @clarkemily To avoid downvoting you should try to be clear with your question. You should also use MathJax for a proper editing and show your effort to solve the problem.

Comment: yeah you are right. it's been editted though